# Software recommendation for creating a secure backup server resilient against crypto trojans - configure user to only have permission to add new files

Tags: ransomware, backup

I'm really afraid of crypto trojans stealing saved credentials for my NAS and encrypting all my backups.

I know I could turn off the NAS while not backing up but I want some convenience.

The backups are done using dejá-dup (Ubuntu's built-in backup solution).

As far as I know, dejá-dup only creates new files and does not modify existing archives.

The easiest solution I can think of is creating a share that only allows adding new files but not delete or modify existing ones. I did not find such an option on my QNAP TS 2-bay NAS - and on FreeNAS I cannot even find the place to set up FTP.

Which software would you recommend for my use case? Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could snapshot the QNAP/FreeNAS storage regularily. You can fall back to an older backup snapshot if you notice the corruption before the backup snapshots are deleted.

Client-Server backup systems like [UrBackup](https://www.urbackup.org/) (has a QNAP package), [BackupPC](https://backuppc.github.io/backuppc/), [Bacula](https://www.bacula.org/) or [Burp](https://burp.grke.org/) prevent deletion of backups from the client (if login credentials for those are different). It would depend on where you want to run the server and what kind of other systems you want to backup to narrow it down between those.

Comment: I like the idea :)